# Supremum of the difference of two Brownian motion with a drift

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

How can one compute $P(\sup_{0\leq s\leq t} (c_1X_1(s) - c_2X_2(s))>x)$, where $x>0$, $c_1, c_2$ are two fixed constants and $X_i$'s are Brownian motions with a drift, i.e. $X_i(t) = \mu_it+\sigma B_i(t)$, $i =1,2$, and $B_1(t)$ and $B_2(t)$ are independent standard Brownian motions? This is just a problem from my studying packet for my exam. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are the Brownian motions independent?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Yes. I. made the correction in my problem.

Comment: In this case, $c_1X_1(t)+c_2X_2(t)$ is also a Brownian motion with drift.

Comment: @JohnDawkins We use then the fact that $\{sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} B(t) < x\}$, where $B(t)$ is a BM with a drift, is equivalent to $\{\tau_x > t\}$, where $\tau_x$= the first time the BM hits x?

Comment: Precisely!     $\phantom{bbbbb}$

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you for your help!